# swiftで開発していたスマホアプリを ReactNative に置き換えた際、swiftアプリ内部のデータをReactNativeアプリでも引き継げるようにしたい

Tags: swift, react-native

## 実現したいこと

swiftで開発していたスマホアプリを ReactNative に置き換えた際、swiftアプリ内部のデータをReactNativeアプリでも引き継げるようにしたい

## 前提

現在、swift により作成&リリースされたスマホアプリがあります。swift エンジニアが居なくなることに伴い、自分の開発経験が豊富な ReactNative に移行して、運用・保守していこうと考えています。この場合、もとの swift でリリースされたアプリの内部に保存してあるデータをReactNativeのアプリに引き継ぐ方法はありますか？
swiftではRealmを使ってデータをアプリ内部に保存していました。

また、アカウント機能などはないため、バックエンドを用意してアプリのデータをクラウドにバックアップして、アプリの更新後に再ダウンロードするような仕組みを実装することはできないと考えています。